# Assembly programming

Tags: assembly, type-conversion

I'm new at programming assembly. Now I'm trying to write a program that converts number from decimal to binary, but I got stuck with one problem. After user enters number(from 0 to 65535) I have to convert it from ascii character to ascii integer that I could start converting from decimal to binary. If it is one number(from 0 to 9) I guess I can easily do this by writing:

```
     SUB ax, 48
```

But this would work only by typing one number...
How could I convert typed number in ascii integer, if number is higher? I thought about separating string into characters, but I have no idea how I could do that.

This is part of my program that I have already written:

```
    .MODEL small
    .Stack 100h

    .DATA
    msg1 db 'input decimal number from from 0 to 65535: $'
    msg2 db 0Dh,0Ah,'number in binary: $' 
    number db 255, ?, 256 dup ('$')

    .CODE
  start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds,ax
    mov dx, offset msg1 
    mov ah,09h
    int 21h
    mov ah, 0Ah 
    mov dx, offset number
    int 21h 


    mov ax,04C00h
    int 21h

 end start
```

Comment: What's a "decimal number"? What's a "binary number"? Is the number of fingers on your hand decimal or binary?

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop for each character of input. For each, subtract to get an integer between 0 and 9. To "move to the next digit" you need to multiply your current value by 10 and then add the next one.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a number or want to print it you need to convert to/from ascii so you are right about subtracting 48.

Now if user enter something like "123" you cant just subtract. You need to:

- split number into digits
- make number again

Now think about it. "123" is actually `1*100+2*10+3` so the pseudocode would be:

```
A = readNumber
exp = 10^A.length
result = 0
for i = 0, i < A.length, i++ do
  result += A[i]*exp
  exp /= 10
end
```

In assembly language it would be something like:

```
mov ah, 0Ah 
mov dx, offset number
int 21h 

; now number[1] index holds total read characters including RET
mov cx, number[1]
dec cx    ; we need length without RET
mov ax, 10
.makeExponent:
mul 10    ; MUL multiplies AX with an argument and stores in AX if argument is byte sized
loop .makeExponent
; now CX = 0, AX = exponent
mov dx, ax ; Store exponent in DX

mov cx, number[1] ;CX = digit count again
mov si, offset number
inc si
inc si ; SI shows into number[0], we need to show for number[2] for the first digit
cld    ; lodsb instruction does INC SI if DF=0. CLD makes DF=0

xor ax, ax ; AX = 0
xor bx, bx ; BX = 0, BX will be result

.decode
lodsb  ;Load value from DS:SI into AL and increment SI
sub ax, 48   ; ASCII->number
mul dx       ; Multiply by exponent. Like in 123 case here 1*100, next loop 2*10, then 3*1
add bx, dx   ; Add what we've got to result. For 123 case it's 100+20+3
mov ax, dx   ; DIV and MUL work only for AX, so move exponent to AX
div 10       ; divide it by 10(100, then 10, then 1)
xchg dx, ax  ; And exchange DX and AX values
loop .decode

; BX is your result
```

Now I haven't coded in a while in assembly language so some things may be off like:
I assume that `mul dx` stores the lowest bits of result in DX so I add DX to BX. It may be you need to add AX value to BX. The same goes for DIV.

Also `xor val, val` means val = 0. That was a long time ago faster than `mov val, 0` now I just like it.